# Insert Large JSON in a Cassandra Table

Tags: cassandra, nosql

[The image shows error detail- Please click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcQ5b.png)
I am trying to Insert large JSON in a column of Cassandra Table.
Table Schema looks like :

```
Table1 (EmployeeName text, EmployeeID text, EmployeeJSON text )

INSERT INTO Table1 (EmployeeName, EmployeeID, EmployeeJSON)
VALUES ('Razzaq','234',"Jason String")
```

NOte : JSON string is huge one. It has size of 212k. How can I insert that into this table. Either Should I Use same method or something else?

Comment: what driver are you using?

Comment: Are you getting any error while inserting the record? Or, the question is more of what's best way to do it?

Comment: @AlexOtt I am new to Cassandra. I am using DataStax DevCenter. I am SQL server database. I have started learning Cassandra. I am using simple insert statement. I am attaching image.

Comment: DevCenter is just an interactive tool for experimenting with schema, etc. - it wasn't designed to be used for such big inserts, etc. Instead you need to use driver for specific programming language

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks for your comments. I got the solution. I enclosed my JSON withon double Dollar sign ($$) and inserted my data with no error. i-e 

INSERT INTO Table1 (EmployeeName, EmployeeID, EmployeeJSON)
VALUES ('Razzaq','234',$$Jason String$$)

Answer (score 0):

You could insert it using `fromJson()` function for a single column value.

> It may only be used in the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement or as one of the column values in an UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT statement. For example, it cannot be used in the selection clause of a SELECT statement.

Example:

```
Table1 (EmployeeName text, EmployeeID text, EmployeeJSON text )

INSERT INTO Table1 (EmployeeName, EmployeeID, EmployeeJSON)
VALUES ('Razzaq','234',fromJson('{
    "employeeCompany" : "Acme Corp",
    "employeeCountry" : "Egypt",
    "employeeSalary" : [{
        "currency" : "Dollar",
        "salaryVariance" : { "cashPay" : 90%, "equity" : 10% }
    }]           
}'))
```

[Json Support in Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/json.html)